# What is this S-shaped icon that appear on top of samsung screen/indicator bar?

Tags: applications

[image]

What is this S-shaped icon that appear on top of samsung screen/indicator bar?

Answer (score 1):

The icon appears to belong to [360 Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qihoo.security) by Qihoo.